# Jelastic Wordpress site installed in subdirectory and set does not work for the root domain

Tags: php, wordpress, subdirectory, document-root, jelastic

I want to have a WordPress site directly in the domain of access. without the WP files are actually in the main folder.

For example: I install WordPress in a **/blog** folder (example.com/blog), and I can configure to access is directly in the domain (example.com) without the folder name included. (in this case the /blog folder).

The advantage is that the main folder is more organized and existing scripts in other folders function normally and beyond to improve safety.

I have run this easily in my development environment on my macbook air, according to the simple instructions:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

However, in doing so created the environment in **Jelastic**, this is not working.

Someone could do this on **Jelastic**? Place the wordpress installation in a folder and then configured to access the root domain by **Jelastic**?

---

My Additional Information:

I'm using a trial account to test **Jelastic**.

Environments created in which attempts were failures have been:

1. Environment 1: NGINX 1.4.3 (loadbalacer) + Apache 2.2 + 5.5 +
   Memcached MariaDB 1.4.15;
2. Environments 2: Apache 2.2 + MariaDB 5.5;

Jelastic only works in root for me with Apache Server. With NGINX Server (not like loadbalancer) impossible the install wordpress.

Comment: Did you ask your hosting provider for help with this issue? It's the kind of problem that's much easier to troubleshoot and solve with a real life example in front of you...

Comment: I'm in a period of Jelastic TRIAL. And for the support of the provider is necessary to create another independent account ... And I want to test before this and available to Jelastic support during this period was here in the community. Finally, I hope my question, can collaborate with new users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Jelastic only works in root for me with Apache Server. With NGINX Server (not like loadbalancer) impossible the install wordpress.

While installing WP to Nginx I have faced with some problems too and found solution.

I have deployed WP to context **/blog** then opened in the browser and after I clicked on **Create Configuration File** nothing happened but I received the link in address line like:

http://example.com/blog/index.php/blog/wp-admin/setup-config.php

To continue the installation you need to remove one of the **blog/index.php**

Example: http://example.com/blog/wp-admin/setup-config.php

Then I have successfully installed WP.

If you want to have a WordPress site directly in the domain of access without the WP files are actually in the main folder with Nginx Server you need:

Install WP to needed context example.com/blog

Change Site Address (URL) in WP to example.com/

Then find in Nginx Config Manager **conf**> **nginx.conf** at 41 line such text and change directory **ROOT** to **blog**:

```
include /etc/nginx/aliases.conf;
    location / {
        root   /var/www/webroot/blog;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            location ~ /\. { deny all; access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/webroot/blog$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www/webroot/blog;
```

Save the file and restart Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

To have a WordPress site directly in the domain of access without the WP files are actually in the main folder you need:

Install WP to needed context example.com/blog

Change Site Address (URL) in WP to example.com/

Then find in Apache Config Manager **conf**> **httpd.conf** at 960 line such text:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/webroot/ROOT
ServerName website.jelastic.com
ServerAlias *
ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.jelastic.com-error_log
CustomLog logs/dummy-host.jelastic.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Change **DocumentRoot /var/www/webroot/ROOT** to **DocumentRoot /var/www/webroot/blog**

Save the file and restart Apache.